# Use main script tags for fetched ajax data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Is it anyhow possible to use the scripts of `index.php` from the new fetched data from ajax? I did a bunch of researches and still no answer!

index.php

```
<script>
function callMe(){
alert("hi");
}
</script>

...

<div id="LoadHere">
<button onClick="callMe()">Click</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadit(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'result.php',
    method:"POST",
    success: function(data){
      $('#LoadHere').append(data);
    }
  });
  }

function loadFetch(){
   loadit();
}

</script>
<button onClick="loadFetch();">LOAD FETCH</button>
```

result.php

```
<button onClick="callMe()"></button>
```

Comment: yeah for example after the site is fully loaded, then the data are fetched, they are useless, without function, I basicly have to put at `result.php` the whole script!
And its not logical to do it, cuz if I have multiple fetches same script will be loaded multiple time, and in one click i get multiple popups!

Comment: I thought that should work, but just tried it and it doesn't.  I can give you code to make that specific example work, but it really depends on what you're really getting from the ajax call, and how many things you want to handle.

Comment: okay i have edited my post with more details, it the simpliest explanation of the issue, i want to develope a online shopping, when you scroll down new article will load, but if i press on the article no effect! I have to put the script on the result.php file, but it fetches multiple time the script and it calls it multiple time!

Comment: I've given a basic example and the gone into a bit more depth about how to handle multiple similar elements, which I'm expecting suits your situation more.

Comment: That would definitely work: http://jsfiddle.net/49rcy8ew/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take out the inline event handler from the button and assign a delegate event handler to the container then you can do it like this...

```
$("#LoadHere").on("click", "button", function() {
    callMe();
});
```

Change the button to just...

```
<button>call me</button>
```

Here's a working fiddle example, with a post to get the html...

http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/s8e67kav/5/

(I'd post a snippet but I'm using the jsfiddle echo url to "request" the HTML)

---

**Event Delegation**

In short, you're assigning a click event handler to the element with the ID `LoadHere`, and whenever you click anything *inside* that element it will see if it matches the 2nd criteria, in this case a button.  If it does then the event handler is executed.  If you just want to assign an event handler to a specific element or group of elements then you don't need the 2nd parameter.  It would just be...

```
$("#elementId").on("click", function() {
    // do something when clicked
});
```

---

**Note:** Since you're looking at loading multiple similar elements I'd recommend giving the button a class name, so that the event handler will work for all of them...

For example:

```
$("#LoadHere").on("click", ".callMe", function() {
    callMe();
});

<button class="callMe">call me</button>
```

That makes it very clear what the button is for, what event handler will handle the clicks, and what happens when it is clicked.  It's much easier to maintain if you keep it clear like that.

Comment: After the page loads, the fetch should happen than to call a function, I have to use .append() to add more buttons, and in each button I have to call the `alert("hi");`

Comment: You created the click event handler for the load button incorrectly.  I've fixed it here... http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/s8e67kav/13/.  I'll explain event delegation in the answer - it should explain what was wrong there.

Comment: Thank you, that was it what Ive been searching!

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)